# How can we help in redemption on Stack-Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Stack Overflow is an amazing search tool for answering and asking important programming questions on all languages. Sometimes questions may get over looked after making important changes to the errors they had made which may have gotten them down-votes or closed. Questions that are closed have a chance to be reevaluated by the website’s bots and monitors.

Should there be a website bot system to recognize questions that have undergone major changes, or might there be a better way to Incentivize those who correct their mistakes?

Comment: I downvoted this because it seems like a rant and I don't fully understand what kind of "redemption" you're expecting. Also, this should be on Stack Overflow meta if you aren't concerned about how relevant this is for the rest of the network. I didn't want to have to characterize this as a rant, but I guess if you asked me to explain my downvote I might as well speak up.

Comment: @Chair that's fair, i definitively show my thoughts on it in the wording, but my point is people that down-vote posts never return when a post is changed and posts with -# don't get a chance for redemption.

Comment: The issue of people downvoting without commenting and never returning to undo their votes after the question has been edited has [received plenty of discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) (and linked posts).

Comment: "*Might it be more reasonable to hold Super users(users with thousands of point) to a higher standard then most users?*" It's always easier to foist the work off on someone else than to take it on yourself. Ask bad questions? It's not your responsibility to ask good questions; it's the responsibility of others to tell you why they're bad and help you fix them.

Comment: @johnsmith: "*i also think we can agree that super users should (not have to) help fixing questions to make the website better*" No, we don't agree. I believe that each user has a responsibility to contribute positively to the site. That means asking good questions. Or downvoting bad questions. There is no moral imperative to make someone else's question better. That doesn't preclude someone from doing so, but it also doesn't mean they are wrong if they have better things to do with their time.

Comment: Do you have an example case of where users had no room for redemption? I'm asking because the amount of users who a) post bad quality or off-topic questions, b) never react to comments asking for clarification or providing help in getting the question better or c) resorting to rants when their post is downvoted is staggering. Users have all the time in the world to work on their post (including reading help center, doing research and some basic debugging), and feedback is usually given very fast. They can improve questions when they are postend and even when they are put on hold.

Comment: So I am not sure why you believe the _resonsibility_ of redeeming questions could lie anywhere else than with the original poster.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but i just don't see the ability for new users to be able to fix their mistakes and re earn any points

Comment: instead of a penalty for your votes what about a notification for changes on posts that weren't received well the first time?

Comment: not where the users has to deal with it all the time but somewhere which if a user wants to use it they could.

Comment: @johnsmith I see the ability for new users to be able to fix their problems and re-earn lost points. I usually stick around questions _for a bit_ and see it a poster reacts to comments. Helped quite some users who did cooperate and walked away with improved questions. But I'll walk away without coming back when there is no reaction, as I can't keep track of every bad post I voted upon. The responsibility is on them.

Comment: @Modus Tollens it's understandable that keeping track of alot of question can be difficult and that why i think there should be some-type of notification tool for those who want to keep track.

Comment: @johnsmith Nooo... Imagine you're doing all that is expected of good user moderatos, and get constantly pinged as a result! That would be horrible. The point is, a person downvoting is not the only one to see it. If a question is improved, other users will see it, too, and vote on it. Those who want to keep track can do so by saving bookmarks in their browser.

Comment: I've casted over ten thousand down votes. Do you really expect me to keep track of all those posts and/or be notified when such post is edited? I rather stay sane.

Comment: @rene i understand were you're coming from (P.S. i've helped in that bot chatroom) could there a chatroom for up-voting worthy questions that a bot had identified as to have changed

Comment: You can always suggest it.

Comment: I wish i didn't originally come off as badly as i did, but i do feel that this is a problem that if fixed could result in users with more quality posts because they were able to fix errors.

Comment: 'fallen from it’s original goal to provide help to anyone on programming questions from knowledgeable programmers' no.  SO is not pay-per-view.  Anyone can search it.

Comment: if you don't agree with the question you're welcome to change it.

Comment: No, we can't; that's not what edits are for.  Edits are only meant to clarify, and fix spelling and grammar.  Changing intent is entirely outside the purview.  Beyond that, it may behoove you to learn what SE is all about, as it seems like you have an incorrect understanding, which is leading to the disconnected expectations you're experiencing.

Answer (score 15):

Voting exists to sort through content. It is a quick way of saying whether some content is good or bad. As such, voting based on the way the question currently exists is perfectly fine. Users can't know what will happen in the future, so they judge it based on what they see.

You can change the question, and maybe users will change their votes based on that. But maybe not. Users are not obligated to frequently check in with bad questions to see if they became good.

Then again, you also could have posted the question well *the first time*, and then your question wouldn't have attracted downvotes to begin with. After all, you had all the time in the world to post that question.

Remember: you are the one who did the wrong thing by posting poor quality content.

Comment: i'm not really looking for obligation from down-voters, but shouldn't there be a responsibility from super users with thousands of points to make the site better by revisiting questions

Comment: @johnsmith: Shouldn't there be a responsibility from users asking questions to ask good questions? Why should "super users with thousands of points" have to expend effort on questions that weren't asked well at first, when they could be expending effort on questions that were well-asked the *first time*? Don't those people deserve to get good answers? People's time is finite.

Comment: I guess you could looking at it either way. Should Super users privileges not come with responsibilities?

Comment: @johnsmith: That only makes sense if those "super users" *asked for* those privileges. Most of us got them simply for providing good content. Reputation is gratitude for contributing useful content. It would be a very perverse system if "gratitude" came with obligations. Especially if those obligations prevent you from continuing to contribute useful content.

Comment: think of this question you would fall into the "super user" category and you could have down-voted the question and left but you didn't, you debate me about it and the result was the question got better

Comment: @johnsmith: No, the question did not get better. Nor is this question of value to people other than yourself.

Comment: you're welcome to edit it if you think that it's a bad question.

Comment: That wasn't meant to be any type of "trap" it was an actual invitation.

Comment: @johnsmith - The invitation to improve this question still exists for you.  I can tell you that your question reads like, the responsibility to improve everyone's contributions, should be on the users who already submit quality contributions.  Except that is already true in many cases, if you could see the work people with access to the review queue do every single day, you would understand what is already done to improve existing good questions and mold them into gems.